# how to access map of map based on inside map value in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a map of map src_grp_map. Now I want to get the inside map which has a pattern string edw.cdim_country in join table key in inside map.

Below is my source map of map

```
      val src_grp_map=Map("edw.dim_cust_extn_odm" -> 
        Map("src_table" -> "edw.dim_cust_extn_odm", "tgt_attribute_count" -> 3, "join_table" -> "edw.dim_cust,edw.cdim_country,NA"),
        "edw.dw_atk_case_general" -> 
          Map("src_table" -> "edw.dw_atk_case_general", "tgt_attribute_count" -> 2, "join_table" -> "NA"))
```

now using src_grp_map I want inside map which contains edw.cdim_country in join_table key
output should be below.

```
Map("src_table" -> "edw.dim_cust_extn_odm", "tgt_attribute_count" -> 3, "join_table" -> "edw.dim_cust,edw.cdim_country,NA")
```

If multiple inside maps contains the pattern string then I need all inside maps.

Comment: It may help if you properly format your code as code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez done. thanks

Comment: Please look up Scala naming conventions. Scala uses camel case instead of snake case

Comment: With proper formatting I was referring to not only changing the font, but splitting the lines to make it easier to visualise the data. Also, what is the type of `src_map`? Are those keys strings? If so, putting them inside quotes would help since we could just copy and paste.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I hope this helps, yes keys are string type. Added quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an interesting problem. However, I think one thing would help you a great deal. Currently, src_grp_map is of type Map[String, Map[String, AnyVal]]. I think it would be better to make it of type Map[String, CustomClass].

So here is my preferred solution:

```
case class TableInfo(srcTable: String, tgtAttributeCount: Int, joinTable: IndexedSeq[String])

val info1 = TableInfo("edw.dim_cust_extn_odm", 3, IndexedSeq("edw.dim_cust", "edw.cdim_country", "NA"))
val info2 = TableInfo("edw.dw_atk_case_general", 2, "NA")

val srcGrpMap = Map("edw.dim_cust_extn_odm" -> info1, "edw.dw_atk_case_general" -> info2)

def getTableInfo(joinTableKey: String, inputMap: Map[String, TableInfo]): IndexedSeq[TableInfo] = inputMap.values.filter(_.joinTable.contains(joinTableKey))
```

Just call getTableInfo function.

Now, if you insist on using your original clunky data format, here is an alternative solution:

```
def getTableInfo(joinTableKey: String, inputMap: Map[String, Map[String, AnyVal]]): IndexedSeq[Map[String, AnyVal]] = {
  inputMap.values.filter{ x =>
    x.get("join_table") match {
      case Some(y) =>
        y match {
          case z: String =>
            z.split(",").contains(joinTableKey)
          case z => false
        }
      case None => 
        false
    }
  }.toIndexedSeq
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve it using below code.

```
     val src_grp_map=Map("edw.dim_cust_extn_odm" ->
      Map("src_table" -> "edw.dim_cust_extn_odm", "tgt_attribute_count" -> 3, "join_table" -> "edw.dim_cust,edw.cdim_country,NA"),
      "edw.dw_atk_case_general" ->
        Map("src_table" -> "edw.dw_atk_case_general", "tgt_attribute_count" -> 2, "join_table" -> "NA"))

    val collect_src_table_values=src_grp_map.map(p=>p._2).toList

    val z=collect_src_table_values.filter(x=>x("join_table").toString().contains("edw.cdim_country"))
```